# REGEX get currency instead of date

Tags: php, regex

I need to read numbers from a string in the format

```
{any number of digits} {period} {two digits}
```

Example:

```
256.23 = 256.23
231.1 = false
2321 = false
das2312.23 = false
```

However, the problem is that in this string there are dates sometimes and I would like to achieve the following effect:

```
20.10.20 = false
23.12 = 23.12
```

I currently have a ReGex like this:

```
(\d+\.\d{2})
```

but this return like this:

```
29.74.23 = 29.74
```

I also tried:

```
(\d+\.\d{2}(?!\.))
```

but it's return = 74.23.

@edit: PHP

Comment: Maybe `\b(?<!\d\.)(\d+\.\d{2})\b(?!\.\d)` would do ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/xWyCFz/1))?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't want surrounding digits or dots and disregarding surrounding dots:

`(?<![.\d])\d+\.\d\d(?![\d.])`

You can always add to the classes to disregard any other *`characters`* not wanted.

But if you go that route, you'd likely need whitespace boundary's instead.

`(?<!\S)\d+\.\d\d(?!\S)`

which is much more potent.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/2SWGUdfg give me error(PHP)

Comment: @SpectrumCodeFrom - Not having errors here, take your pick:  [(?<!\[.\d\])\d+\.\d\d(?!\[\d.\])](https://regex101.com/r/E0WIwW/1) or [(?<!\S)\d+\.\d\d(?!\S)](https://regex101.com/r/netsoB/1). Be sure to know how to escape regex when using Php delimiters though. My software does it automatically, I never think about it.

Comment: @SpectrumCodeFrom You are missing the delimiters in php `preg_match_all('/(?<!\S)\d+\.\d\d(?!\S)/', $content, $matches);`  See https://3v4l.org/mA0E9

Answer (score 1):

If the language where you use this supports it, you would use a lookbehind and lookahead, so start with `(?<=(?:\s|^))` and end with `(?=(?:\s|$))` i.e. before the match there should be the start of the string, or a space, and similar at the end:

```
(?<=(?:\s|^))(\d+\.\d{2})(?=(?:\s|$))
```

Of course, if the number would always be the only thing in the string, you could just use:

```
^(\d+\.\d{2})$
```

`(?<=(?:\s|^))` explained:

- the `(?<=..)` is a lookbehind expression, meaning "check that this comes immediately before"
- the `(?:\s|^)` just means "match either whitespace or the start of the line" and thanks to the `?:` it doesn't become a numbered group.

`(?=(?:\s|$))` is similar, except that `$` is the end of the line and it starts with `?=`, which means "check that this comes immediately after"

@thefourthbird correctly pointed out that you can avoid the non-capturing group in this case (since it's already in the lookbehind/lookahead parentheses):

```
(?<=\s|^)(\d+\.\d{2})(?=\s|$)
```

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/bgbw6C/1 and my script in PHP get fatal error. https://pastebin.com/HsErkCFL PHP not support it or I doing something bad?

Comment: @SpectrumCodeFrom You can omit the nested non capture group `(?<=\s|^)\d+\.\d{2}(?=\s|$)` See https://3v4l.org/ctXuP

Comment: @SpectrumCodeFrom give it a try without the non-capturing group (see edit), if that still doesn't work, it's possible your language doesn't support lookahead and lookbehind. In that case you should provide some more details about the context in which you need this, since there are other possibilities, depending on context.

Comment: You're welcome - if you feel the question has been answered, consider clicking the checkmark, so the question no longer appears as unanswered